# Elasticsearch query to match different values for same nested field

Tags: elasticsearch, bigdata

I'm trying to fetch documents which have two names in a nested document however the `must` clause is working as "OR" instead of "AND". 
Here is the example:

Mapping:

```
curl  -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index" -d '
{
  "mappings": {
    "blogpost": {
      "properties": {
        "comments": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "name":    { "type": "keyword"   },
            "age":     { "type": "short"   }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Indexing 3 documents:

```
curl  "http://localhost:9200/my_index/blogpost/1" -d '
{
  "title": "doc1",
  "comments": [
    {
      "name":    "John Smith",
      "age":     28
    },
    {
      "name":    "Alice White",
      "age":     31
    }
  ]
}
'

curl  "http://localhost:9200/my_index/blogpost/2" -d '
{
  "title": "doc2",
  "comments": [
    {
      "name":    "Luther Lawrence",
      "age":     21
    },
    {
      "name":    "Alice White",
      "age":     19
    }
  ]
}
'

curl  "http://localhost:9200/my_index/blogpost/3" -d '
{
  "title": "doc3",
  "comments": [
    {
      "name":    "Tadhg Darragh",
      "age":     22
    },
    {
      "name":    "Alice White",
      "age":     31
    },
    {
      "name":    "Lorene Hicks",
      "age":     44
    }
  ]
}
'
```

I'm looking for documents which have `comments.name` with `"Alice White"` **and** `"John Smith"` in the same document, using above data only document `id 1` would match. I tried with this query:

```
curl  "http://localhost:9200/my_index/blogpost/_search" -d '
{
  "_source": { "include": "title" },
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "comments",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "terms": { "comments.name": ["John Smith", "Alice White"] } }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

It matches with all documents because all documents have "John Smith" or "Alice White". 
Improving this query to have two separated matches `query.nested.query.bool.must[].terms`, one matcher for each value:

```
curl  "http://localhost:9200/my_index/blogpost/_search" -d '
{
  "_source": { "include": "title" },
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "comments",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "term": { "comments.name": "John Smith" } },
            { "term": { "comments.name": "Alice White" } }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

So, my question is, how to build a query to match only documents with `"Alice White"` **and** `"John Smith"`?

ps. Dropped a script with the [example here](https://gist.github.com/shairontoledo/0a33acea6f269c277058e078b7d02c21)

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "_source": {
    "include": "title"
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "comments",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "comments.name": [
                        "John Smith"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "comments",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "comments.name": [
                        "Alice White"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding one nested block for every name is very verbose but solves the problem, thanks.

Comment: Might be verbose but that's the way to do it.